# combine 2 dataframes with a duplicate common identifier in both

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes both having the exact same column names and I am trying to combine them both where both and preferring the second df for conflicting data

df1:

```
A,B,C,D
123,xyz,S1,1111
123,xyz,S1,1111
234,mno,S3,2222
999,abc,S9,9999
999,abc,S9,9999
```

df2:

```
A,B,C,D
123,abc,S1,1234
123,abc,S1,1234
123,abc,S1,1234
123,cde,S2,2345
234,nop,S3,
567,pqr,S5,5555
```

I wanted to have the following output:

```
A,B,C,D
123,abc,S1,1234
123,abc,S1,1234
123,abc,S1,1234
123,cde,S2,2345
234,nop,S3,
567,pqr,S5,5555
999,abc,S9,9999
999,abc,S9,9999
```

i.e., use column A as a common identifier in both, and take data from both df1 and df2 for non-conflicting rows (preserving duplicates) and for conflicting rows, prefer the df2's rows (preserving duplicates)

I tried doing the combine operation like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv1_data), dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv2_data), dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)

df1.set_index(['A'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['A'], inplace=True)

result_df = df2.combine_first(df1)

result_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(result_df)
```

but getting the following result:

```
      A    B   C     D
0   123  abc  S1  1234
1   123  abc  S1  1234
2   123  abc  S1  1234
3   123  abc  S1  1234
4   123  abc  S1  1234
5   123  abc  S1  1234
6   123  cde  S2  2345
7   123  cde  S2  2345
8   234  nop  S3      
9   567  pqr  S5  5555
10  999  abc  S9  9999
11  999  abc  S9  9999
```

this is preserving data when there's non-conflicting rows (i.e., 999 is seen twice as expected) but its duplicating rows for the conflicting ones (i.e., 123 is seen 8 times instead of 4 times)

*EDIT*:
Note that the indexes can be multiple so instead of just 'A', there can be ['A', 'A1', 'A2'...] and it would be dynamically set before combine even takes place. Also note that the data can be in millions which is truncated here for simplicity.

Comment: can you please [edit] your question with all the details?

Comment: I am sorry, I have included everything except the possibility of indexes being multiple. will include that too, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `df1` filtering out rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
var = 'A'
df = pd.concat([df2, df1[~df1[var].isin(df2[var])]], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
     A    B   C     D
0  123  abc  S1  1234
1  123  abc  S1  1234
2  123  abc  S1  1234
3  123  cde  S2  2345
4  234  nop  S3      
5  567  pqr  S5  5555
6  999  abc  S9  9999
7  999  abc  S9  9999
```

How it working:

```
var = 'A'
print (df1[~df1[var].isin(df2[var])])
     A    B   C     D
3  999  abc  S9  9999
4  999  abc  S9  9999
```

EDIT: If need test by multiple columns convert them to `Index/MultiIndex` first and pass column(s) to list:

```
cols = ['A']
#multiple columns
#cols = ['A', 'B', ...]

df = pd.concat([df2,
                df1[~df1.set_index(cols).index.isin(df2.set_index(cols).index)]],
                ignore_index=True)
print (df)
     A    B   C     D
0  123  abc  S1  1234
1  123  abc  S1  1234
2  123  abc  S1  1234
3  123  cde  S2  2345
4  234  nop  S3      
5  567  pqr  S5  5555
6  999  abc  S9  9999
7  999  abc  S9  9999
```

If use `set_index` first, solution is similar:

```
cols = ['A']
df1.set_index(cols, inplace=True)
df2.set_index(cols, inplace=True)

df = (pd.concat([df2,
                df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
     A    B   C     D
0  123  abc  S1  1234
1  123  abc  S1  1234
2  123  abc  S1  1234
3  123  cde  S2  2345
4  234  nop  S3      
5  567  pqr  S5  5555
6  999  abc  S9  9999
7  999  abc  S9  9999
```

Comment: the primary key is a configurable field in this application, meaning I have a variable which contains the PK and it could potentially be Multiple columns as well. how do tackle that?

Comment: I tried: result_df = pd.concat([df2, df1[~df1.A.isin(df2.A)]], ignore_index=True) but its not getting 999 rows this time

Comment: @SpaceyBot - If need only one key, use first solution, now edited. If need test oe or multiple columns for test membership, use last solution

Comment: for the last solution, why are you setting the index yourself, this would have been set already in prior steps (before combine even takes place).

Comment: @SpaceyBot - Then is not necessary use `.reset_index()` if use this way. But you are right, it is also solution. I can EDIT answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter `df1` with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) on `A` to remove the values that are also present in `df2`, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the two DataFrames in order:

```
key = 'A'

out = pd.concat([df2, df1[~df1[key].isin(df2[key])]], ignore_index=True)
```

For multiple keys, filter with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
keys = ['A']

tmp = (df1.merge(df2[keys].drop_duplicates(),
                 how='outer', indicator=True)
          .loc[lambda x: x.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')]
      )

out = pd.concat([df2, tmp], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     A    B   C       D
0  123  abc  S1  1234.0
1  123  abc  S1  1234.0
2  123  abc  S1  1234.0
3  123  cde  S2  2345.0
4  234  nop  S3     NaN
5  567  pqr  S5  5555.0
6  999  abc  S9  9999.0
7  999  abc  S9  9999.0
```

Intermediates:

```
     A    B   C     D   isin      ~
0  123  xyz  S1  1111   True  False
1  123  xyz  S1  1111   True  False
2  234  mno  S3  2222   True  False
3  999  abc  S9  9999  False   True
4  999  abc  S9  9999  False   True

# df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])
     A    B   C     D
3  999  abc  S9  9999
4  999  abc  S9  9999
```

Intermediate for multiple keys:

```
# df1.merge(df2[keys].drop_duplicates(), how='outer', indicator=True)
     A    B    C       D      _merge
0  123  xyz   S1  1111.0        both
1  123  xyz   S1  1111.0        both
2  234  mno   S3  2222.0        both
3  999  abc   S9  9999.0   left_only
4  999  abc   S9  9999.0   left_only
5  567  NaN  NaN     NaN  right_only

# tmp
      A    B   C       D
9   999  abc  S9  9999.0
10  999  abc  S9  9999.0
```

##### using the index

If your keys are set as index, then just [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) `df1` rows based on `df2` (with `errors='ignore'` to ignore the non-existent keys):

```
# keys = ['A']
# df1.set_index(keys, inplace=True)
# df2.set_index(keys, inplace=True)

out = pd.concat([df2, df1.drop(df2.index, errors='ignore')])
```

Output:

```
       B   C       D
A                   
123  abc  S1  1234.0
123  abc  S1  1234.0
123  abc  S1  1234.0
123  cde  S2  2345.0
234  nop  S3     NaN
567  pqr  S5  5555.0
999  abc  S9  9999.0
999  abc  S9  9999.0
```

Comment: I cannot use df['A'] as its part of index (which I cannot change), and also is it a better solution performance-wise considering the data would be in millions?

Comment: @SpaceyBot I think pre-filtering is the most efficient approach.  I updated for variable keys

Comment: Getting the following error:
KeyError: "None of [Index(['A'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @SpaceyBot I can't reproduce your error, with either of my codes, please double check or provide a reproducible example. What is your pandas version?

Comment: the second solution is throwing this error since 'A' is not found in any of the columns as its set as index. please double check my *EDIT* section. your code only works if I don't set index prior to merge operation.

Comment: @SpaceyBot so you made the keys as index?

Comment: yes, which was necessary for other operations that I perform with the df before merge or combine even takes place (which is irrelevant to the question that's why not mentioned)

Comment: @SpaceyBot I see, then it's even easier, just `drop` the keys, see the update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256751/discussion-between-spaceybot-and-mozway).